Best way to find multiple ids in list of files in spark scala
I have a list of IDs that I want to find in my parquet files. For each of the IDs I do have an idea in which files they could be present i.e. I would have a mapping where I have 
ID1 -> file1, file2 
ID2 -> file2, file5 
ID -> file3, file4 and so on...

What would be best way in spark scala to do such a task. I thought of plenty ways. 

Grouping by file, reading it and creating a join to IDs. (Can use Future to parallelize this)
Read all files in a single df and then filter out the IDs. 

Which method would be the best given there are 1000s of IDs and millions of rows in each file. Or is there any other better method?  
EDIT: Option 1 can possibly reduce the search space by eliminating a few files I need to search.

I'm not sure I understand your two options. I think they're the same from a Spark POV. Keep in mind that it is Spark's job to parallelize the work for you, and there's most of the time no reason to use Future with Spark. Anyway, performance in such situations will highly depend on your infrastructure and your actual data, you should try and measure.

In option 1, I am opening files iteratively and finding IDs in it, basically reading and filtering in a loop. While for option 2, I will be reading all the files and then applying filter on it.
As for Future in option 1, won't it help with finding IDs in multiple files at once?

By doing 2, Spark will distribute the read/filter operations. This is why I say it's kinda the same as what you're describing in option 1. (I'm assuming the files are stored on a distributed filesystem, right?).

Yes, but option 1 might eliminate need to search a few files. Lets say I already found ID1 in file1, now I won't have to search it in file2 and in few of the cases I might even have to not ready file2 at all.
